# jersey rest web service to return list of objects where objects contain byte array for file

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, multipart

The problem is to return list of files with some file related information.

Here is my web service class:

```
@Path("/pdfsigning")
public class PdfSigningResource{    

    @EJB
    private PdfSigningFacadeInt pdfSigningFacadeInt;

    @POST
    @Path("/unsignedfilelist")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getUnsignedFileList() {

        List<FileInfoDto> unsignedFileInfoDtoList = pdfSigningFacadeInt
                .getUnsignedFileList();

        GenericEntity<List<FileInfoDto>> genericUnsignedFileInfoDtoList = new GenericEntity<List<FileInfoDto>>(
                unsignedFileInfoDtoList) {
        };
        return Response.ok(Status.OK).entity(genericUnsignedFileInfoDtoList)
                .build();

    }
}
```

FileInfoDto class with getter/setter omitted:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FileInfoDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 303766558349361898L;

    @XmlElement(name = "fileName")
    private String fileName;

    @XmlElement(name = "fileType")
    private String fileType;

    // other fields ...

    @XmlElement(name = "fileByteArray")
    private byte[] fileByteArray;
```

And here is the jersey-1 client:

```
public class FileService implements FileServiceInt {

   public List<FileInfoDto> getUnsignedFileList() {            

       //code to build url  

        WebResource unsignedFileListResource = unsignedFileListClient.resource(url);


        ClientResponse response = unsignedFileListResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)                                        .post(ClientResponse.class);

        if (Constants.CLIENT_RESPONSE_STATUS != response.getStatus()) {
            LOGGER.debug(">>>>>>>>>> Response Not OK <<<<<<<<<<<<<");
            //TODO throw proper exception
        } else {
            LOGGER.debug(">>>>>>>>>> Response OK <<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        }

        // This line throw exception
        List<FileInfoDto> entityList = response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<FileInfoDto>>() {
        });    

        return entityList;
    }

}
```

The response obtained from server is "OK". But the line

```
List<FileInfoDto> entityList = response.getEntity(new GenericType<List<FileInfoDto>>() {
            });
```

throws `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/internet/MimeMultipart`.

In POM, I've the dependency as

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

What am I missing? Cann't we get list of files this way?

Answer (score 1):

For this version of jersey the use of `javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart` requires Java Mail (see [Jersey 1.x documentation / Mail and MIME multipart](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/chapter_deps.html#d4e1840)).

Add this dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```